# How to change the position of a symbol of an irregular shaped polygon feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I have this irregular polygon feature with two separated squares (the bottom left and bottom right ones). When I created symbology, the symbol circle was placed between the two squares (see the red color highlighted). So, could anyone tell me how to move the circle to be inside of the left bottom square?
I am using ArcGIS desktop 10.6.

[image]

Comment: I am using ArcMap

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: You need to cut that polygon in half as it is crossing the +180/-180 longitude.

Comment: It worked! thank you @Hornbydd